# Why do I get "uWSGI Error Python application not found"?

Tags: python, configuration, nginx, uwsgi

I have nginx config:

```
server
{
        listen 80;
        server_name     mail.myserver.com;
        rewrite         ^(.*)   https://$server_name$request_uri?       permanent;
}

server
{
        # By default we listen on all ips including ipv6 on port 443.  We only respond to the server name here.
        # If you have a default ssl website already comment out the next line and uncomment the one after..
        listen 443;
        #listen 443 ssl;
        server_name     mail.myserver.com;

        # Our logs files.
        access_log      /var/log/nginx/iredmail-access.log;
        error_log       /var/log/nginx/iredmail-error.log;

        # Startup SSL using iRedMails certs.
        # If you made the ssl change above you will need to make this one to enable ssl.
        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate         /etc/ssl/certs/iRedMail_CA.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key     /etc/ssl/private/iRedMail.key;
        ssl_session_timeout     5m;

        # We specify our root location to roundcubemail.
        root    /usr/share/apache2/roundcubemail/;
        index   index.html index.php;

        # Aliasing some locations of static files.
        location /iredadmin/static      { alias /usr/share/apache2/iredadmin/static/;}
        location /static                { alias /usr/share/apache2/iredadmin/static/;}
        location /awstats/icon          { alias /usr/share/awstats/icon/;}
        location /awstatsicon           { alias /usr/share/awstats/icon/;}

        # This allows webmail and roundcube as aliases to /mail/. The root is redirected to /mail.
        rewrite ^/roundcubemail /mail/  permanent;
        rewrite ^/webmail       /mail/  permanent;
        rewrite ^/$             /mail/  permanent;

        # This is used to create a comparision to Apaches ability to alias that works with dynamic scripts.
        location ~ /mail(.*)\.php($|/)
        {
                include         fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
                #fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/fpm-iredmail.sock;
                fastcgi_index   index.php;
                fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/apache2/roundcubemail$1.php;
                fastcgi_param   SERVER_NAME     $http_host;
                fastcgi_ignore_client_abort     on;
                fastcgi_intercept_errors        off;
        }
        location ~ /mail(.*)
        {
                autoindex       on;
                alias           /usr/share/apache2/roundcubemail$1;
        }

        location /iredadmin {
                root /usr/share/apache2/iredadmin/;
                uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9001;
                #uwsgi_pass unix:///var/run/uwsgi/app/iredadmin/iredadmin.socket;
                uwsgi_param UWSGI_PYHOME /usr/share/apache2/iredadmin/python-home;
                uwsgi_param UWSGI_CHDIR /usr/share/apache2/iredadmin;
                uwsgi_param UWSGI_SCRIPT iredadmin;
                include uwsgi_params;
        }

        # Our phpMyAdmin service.  Comment this section out if you don't want public access to it.
        location ~ /phpmyadmin(.*)\.php($|/)
        {
                include         fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
                #uwsgi_pass unix:///var/run/uwsgi/app/iredadmin/iredadmin.socket;
                uwsgi_param UWSGI_PYHOME /usr/share/apache2/iredadmin/python-home;
                uwsgi_param UWSGI_CHDIR /usr/share/apache2/iredadmin;
                uwsgi_param UWSGI_SCRIPT iredadmin;
                include uwsgi_params;
        }

        # Our phpMyAdmin service.  Comment this section out if you don't want public access to it.
        location ~ /phpmyadmin(.*)\.php($|/)
        {
                include         fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
                #fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/fpm-iredmail.sock;
                fastcgi_index   index.php;
                fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/phpmyadmin$1.php;
                fastcgi_param   SERVER_NAME     $http_host;
                fastcgi_param   HTTPS           on;
                fastcgi_param   HTTP_SCHEME     https;
                fastcgi_ignore_client_abort     on;
                fastcgi_intercept_errors        off;
                port_in_redirect                off;
        }
        location ~ /phpmyadmin(.*)
        {
                autoindex       on;
                alias           /usr/share/phpmyadmin$1;
        }
}
```

And I get the error **"uWSGI Error Python application not found"** if I go to **/iredmail**

uwsgi config:

```
[uwsgi]
plugins=python
vhost=true
socket=127.0.0.1:9001
file=/usr/share/apache2/iredadmin/iredadmin.py
```

nginx log:

```
...
2013/07/30 14:47:04 [error] 15947#0: *56 open() "/usr/share/apache2/roundcubemail/favicon.ico" failed (2: No such file or directory ...
```

uwsgi log:

```
AttributeError: 'general'
Tue Jul 30 14:36:33 2013 - unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='mail.myserver.com|') (callable not found or import error)
mail.myserver.com [pid: 17788|app: -1|req: -1/2] 146.52.44.87 () {50 vars in 1421 bytes} [Tue Jul 30 14:36:33 2013] GET /iredadmin => generated 48 bytes in 9 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 2 headers in 63 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/apache2/iredadmin/iredadmin.py", line 9, in <module>
    from libs import iredbase
  File "/usr/share/apache2/iredadmin/libs/iredbase.py", line 34, in <module>
    webmaster = cfg.general.get('webmaster', 'root')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/web/utils.py", line 76, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError, k
AttributeError: 'general'
Tue Jul 30 14:41:31 2013 - unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='mail.myserver.com|') (callable not found or import error)
mail.myserver.com [pid: 17787|app: -1|req: -1/3] 146.52.44.87 () {48 vars in 1390 bytes} [Tue Jul 30 14:41:31 2013] GET /iredadmin => generated 48 bytes in 4 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 2 headers in 63 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/apache2/iredadmin/iredadmin.py", line 9, in <module>
    from libs import iredbase
  File "/usr/share/apache2/iredadmin/libs/iredbase.py", line 34, in <module>
    webmaster = cfg.general.get('webmaster', 'root')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/web/utils.py", line 76, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError, k
AttributeError: 'general'
Tue Jul 30 14:47:04 2013 - unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='mail.myserver.com|') (callable not found or import error)
mail.myserver.com [pid: 17787|app: -1|req: -1/4] 146.52.44.87 () {50 vars in 1421 bytes} [Tue Jul 30 14:47:04 2013] GET /iredadmin => generated 48 bytes in 6 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 2 headers in 63 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
(END)
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11738239/uwsgi-error-python-application-not-found