# Can't change Python Web.py application Linode example

Tags: python, uwsgi, web.py

I am following this web.py Hello World example:

https://library.linode.com/web-servers/nginx/python-uwsgi/ubuntu-12.04-precise-pangolin#sph_more-information

Now I get the "Hello World!" example from above page perfectly to run in my Browser, but when I want to change the application to my need, e.g. make a fully AJAX app out of it like this:

```
urls = ('/(.*)', 'Index')

application = web.application(urls, globals())

web.config.debug = True

class Index:
def POST(self):
    content = web.input(_method='post')
    return 'Ajax Test Data'

if __name__ == '__main__':application.run()
```

I get the following error (even if I make minor changes to the "application" function from Linode)

> uWSGI Error
>
> Python application not found

How can I get this to work with my own code?

---

I uninstalled the Debian packages and installed the pip package with build-in Python. I also had to clean up / unify my .ini and -xml configuration files.

I then started my app with

```
uwsgi -s /tmp/uwsgi.sock -w app
```

The biggest help came from [this document](http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/Example)

However, I encountered a `web module not found error`, so I rolled back to the Linode example and am currently fiddling around with it, still trying to get my app called from inside the application wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Look at this stackoverflow post:[uwsgi error python application not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11738239/uwsgi-error-python-application-not-found)

You need to kill the old uWSGI process, which is searching for the old instance of the app, which no longer exists because you changed it.

Comment: I always restart uwsgi after an application change. I just can't figure out how to get this to run with my own code. I am almost resorting back to LAMP because this is giving me so much headaches. Found this now, maybe it helps.. http://webtest.pythonpaste.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running the app with `if __name__ == '__main__':application.run()`, you need to "export" WSGI application to uWSGI. By default uWSGI looks for a WSGI callable named `application`, but the `application` you have is not a WSGI callable. So remove `if __name__ == '__main__':application.run()` and replace `application = web.application(urls, globals())` with `application = web.application(urls, globals()).wsgifunc()`.