# How to kill all instance of uwsgi

Tags: python, django, uwsgi

I am trying to upload my project to the server. There is already a project in the server now. I have new project which I want to run and replace the old project with the new one, so I pull the new project to the server. Then I activate the virtual environment and do all the necessary work. Then when I try to run the command:

```
uwsgi --plugins=python --chdir=/var/www/prjt/src/ --socket=127.0.0.1:8889 --module=prjt.wsgi:application &
```

it tell me that

```
probably another instance of uWSGI is running on the same address (127.0.0.1:8889).
bind(): Address already in use [core/socket.c line 761]
```

I searched for similar problems and found some solutions about killing all instance of uwsgi as mentioned in this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11738320) but could not find how to do it.

Answer (score 42):

for me the way to kill uwsgi instances in a bruteforce manner was:

```
sudo pkill -f uwsgi -9
```

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me. Thanks, random dude!

Comment: This should be marked as the answer. If you kill individual processes then they spawn back again. The only way is it to kill all of them in one go

Answer (score 21):

Add a pidfile to your command:

```
uwsgi --plugins=python --chdir=/var/www/prjt/src/ --socket=127.0.0.1:8889 --module=prjt.wsgi:application --pidfile /tmp/myapp.pid
```

Then use

```
uwsgi --stop /tmp/myapp.pid
```

to stop the uwsgi instance in a safe way.

If you didn't specify a pidfile when you started the first instance, you can kill it brutally using

```
kill `pidof uwsgi`
```

Comment: where should I place this pidfile?

Comment: Somewhere that is readable and writable by the uwsgi process, and hopefully not writable by other users. Maybe create a directory for pidfiles inside your home directory.

Comment: I edited my answer to add a more realistic path for your pidfile.

Comment: Smith it shows error permission denied when I try to place it in /var/run(I am running this command in virtual environment)

Comment: Place it in the /tmp directory. Every user can create a file here and since /tmp has the sticky bit set, only the user who created the file can delete it.

Comment: I have already running instance..so in the --module=XXXX.wsgi:application should the XXXX should be old project name or new project name?

Comment: It doesn't matter, the stopping function only looks at the pidfile. If you started the first instance without specifying a pidfile, then you can kill it brutally with a `kill \`pidof uwsgi\`  `

Answer (score 10):

you can get the pid of the uwsgi process here `lsof -t -i tcp:8000`

and kill it then `kill -9 pid`

Comment: If you have more than one process tied to port 8000 `kill -KILL $(lsof -t -i tcp:8000)` will kill them all.

Answer (score 3):

I stop my uwsgi instance by command:

```
kill -INT `cat ${APP_ROOT}/run/uwsgi.pid`
```

This command sends [signal to uwsgi](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Management.html#signals-for-controlling-uwsgi) which cause it to stop.

If you do not know PID than you may:

```
killall -s INT /ve/path/bin/uwsgi
```

[The official documentation](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Management.html)

Answer (score -1):

Simliary, I had that issue too.
And I tried all the way(answer) that written in this page.
BUT Nothing was changed.
So I just restart the computer and the problem is gone!!!!!!!!!!!!
Try it!

Comment: Hmm. Maybe in your case restarting solved the issue. But this question is six years old. Don't you think OP has not yet restarted his computer?

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.